# How to configure unified diff context via git-config?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-config, unified-diff

How can I configure via git-config the unified context so that I don't have to always provide the -U or --unified option with a value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git config --global diff.context <value>
```

will set it to show `<value>` lines of context in any repo you work with.

Comment: How would discover this tidbit?  For example, I looked in the output of "git help diff" and it did not refer me to any config documentation.

Comment: @ChrisCleeland `git help config`

Comment: This configuration option is not available in git 1.7.1. so I had to create an alias around it (I see a gui.diffcontext config option, but setting that makes no difference to the current default of 3 lines.) e.g. git config --global alias.di 'diff --unified=9'